# Does unplugging a television from the wall socket make it safer?

Tags: power, mains

Does unplugging a television from the wall socket make the electronic *safer* (against power surge for example) compared to:

- Plugged in, button on wall socket is off
- Plugged in, button on wall socket is on, power button on television set is off

I've been told that one should always unplug the television besides/instead of using the power button on television. Why should I?

Comment: What do you mean by safer? Are you intending to disassemble or hack it? Do you have children playing around it? Usually the reason for cutting the supply is to avoid the power dissipation due to the losses in the television's power supply when in standby.

Comment: Neither. I am curious if the electronic can be harmed electrically if it is plugged in but the power switch/buttons are off.

Comment: It makes no difference whether the plug is removed or the switch on the socket is turned off, as both break the mains connection. But in this case I'd say the question could be considered off-topic.

Comment: If there is a lightning strike, and your device is plugged in, even if the wall socket is turned off, the high voltage may arc into the device anyway (if the voltage goes above the contacts rated in the wall switch). The TV would then be exposed to a surge, and may fail if it's onboard surge protection is not good enough. When a TV is merely "off" from the remote, it is fully live and active, just in a low power standby mode. It consumes power through DC-DC conversion power circuits and the circuitry required to receive IR signals and wake up the controller.

Comment: It should also be noted that, at least in the US, some switches only break the hot wire, rather then the hot and neutral. If you have a break in the bonding of the neutral, or your house is mis-wired, there may be mains power on the still-connected wire.

Comment: @ConnorWolf In my scenario the switches break only the hot wire. Could you please add more detail to your comment and post as answer?

Answer (score 2):

If the power button on your TV is a hard button (like the I/O button at the back of your PC case), it should completely cut the power lines from your TV set. It's just like that you unplugged your cable! But if your TV power button is a soft button, (like a push button) then the ac-dc converter of you TV is working and the controller circuit inside is on and working (but of-course the LCD row/column IC drivers are off). the TV is consuming some power but as long as there is no disturbance in your home AC power, there is no harm on the electronics circuit inside your TV set!
My home TV has a soft button, and I myself unplug the cable when I'm away traveling for a few days! :)

Comment: Good point about the "soft button". I have an old TV with a soft button that often turns itself fully on during storms when there is brief fluctuations in power.

Answer (score 0):

**My guestimates based on too many decades experience:**

**Risks with various disconnection schemes - guestimated:**

- Electronic "off"  - zappable but some resistance. Lightning strike on lines within miles MAY damage. But usually expect no failure in device lifetime.
- 1 wire physical break on live side with other leg at earth = fail only in major lightning strike on local lines and maybe not then. Safe as houses*.
- 1 wire physical break on ground side live side with other leg live.
  Get rid of it. Dangerous to all anyway. Lightning strike would be doing you a favour.
  Note that some systems do not allow you to tell with certainty whether this or prior case applies. The fact that the authorities allow it does not make it nice.
- 2 wire physical break. Could die if lightning hits house or very close by. So could you - even with no TV. 
  ie safe as houses*.
  If the house catches fire the TV may too.
- Pull out plug at wall.
  Very very very slightly safer than above, but not worth the effort compared to the minimal risk level. If you do this sort of thing in all areas of life then staying in bed all day to reduce your risk factor (which it may not do) may be attractive.

---

**Lightning & surge while operating:**

"Some sort" of surge suppressor is an extremely good idea for electronic equipment. The very best does not usually seem necessary. Almost anything seems to be good enough often enough. If you NEED the very best surge protection then a UPS with hard break from main at all times may be as cheap.

- **Proximate lightning:** I have had TWO multifunction printers damaged by lightning strikes near my home over about 30 years - BUT they also had a phone connection (all underground except for street to house feed) and actual strike was probably 100m plus closest. I have never had anything else damaged that way - then and at all other times, all things are plugged in always and "just work".
- **Operating Equipment - General power surge:**   A power 'blip' occasionally resets clocks and computers when power is off long enough to reset them and/or shut them down. I recently had an OPERATING  desktop PC BIOS corruption due to a power surge caused by a local substation accident. This was repaired by an automatic BIOS backup copy write - a feature that I was unaware that the motherboard had. VERY rare.